# python error : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'. How to fix this?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I write the code to transform some images, but this error happened. the error is in this line

```
new_img = np.add(nul_img, np.array([beta]))
```

the error says this

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I have tried to run the code on my friends computer and it worked, but not on my computer

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

alpha = float(input('Enter The alpha value [1.0-3.0]'))
beta = int(input('Enter the beta value [0-100]:' ))

img = cv2.imread('spider.jpg')

nul_img = cv2.multiply(img, np.array([alpha]))
new_img = np.add(nul_img, np.array([beta]))
new_img = np.uint8(new_img)
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using? It could be that the numpy package version is different.

Comment: I suppose you haven't wrong path for your `imread` function, which mean you don't have correct path.

Comment: my version is pyhon 3.7.3

Comment: `img` is `None` in the first case. You have the correct path?

Comment: Print the variables please.

Comment: The error message seems to be saying you are adding a `None` to an `integer`. (as mentioned above.)